# Insert in to 2 tables from 2 tables from a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to read data from 2 tables and inserting to similar tables in a different database.

Here is my query

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

Delete from aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Places]
DECLARE @AutoID int;
insert into aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Places] (ReferenceID, Name, OtherKnownNames, Description, Email)
select ReferenceID, Name, OtherKnownNames, Description, Email from DB_A290D0_places. 
[dbo].[places]
where PublishingStatus=0

SELECT @AutoID = scope_identity();

insert into aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Schedules] (Timing, Type, PlaceID)
select [Timing], [Type], @AutoID from DB_A290D0_places.[dbo].[Schedules]

COMMIT
```

I am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near '@AutoID'.

and even I am not sure that it will work or not.
'Places' table has ID field which is auto id and it is used as FK in Schedule table, so for every 'place' row I need to get auto id and insert it into the schedule table along with the corresponding table data from another database.

**Update1** : I have fixed the syntax error, I can see records added into the table but last generated AutoID is being used for all rows in child table. I want to use autoid generated for each row.

**Update2** : following script worked

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

Delete from aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Places]
declare @NewId table (ID int);
insert into aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Places] (ReferenceID, Name, OtherKnownNames, Description, Email)
select ReferenceID, Name, OtherKnownNames, Description, Email from DB_A290D0_places. 
[dbo].[places]
where PublishingStatus=0

output Inserted.ID into @NewId (ID)

insert into aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Schedules] (Timing, [Type], PlaceID)
  select [Timing], [Type], P.ID
  from DB_A290D0_places.[dbo].[Schedules] S
  inner join @NewId P on P.ID = S.PlaceId;

COMMIT
```

Comment: What would be the value of PlaceID which is auto id of the parent column? every row will generate a new placeid and I want to use that in schedule table placeid column.

Comment: Looking for the example on how to use output to generate id in parent row and use that in child table row

Comment: I don't see how your code work? Because you are joining the new ID on the old ID? It might only work while you test it, but not for real I don't think? Your output clause is in the wrong place even?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store more than one value in a variable, the the line `SELECT @AutoID = scope_identity();` will only capture the last id inserted.

To solve you problem have you considered not changing the ids by setting [IDENTITY_INSERT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and inserting the original ids?

Otherwise use the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to capture the new ids, map them to the old ids, and then insert them into the `Schedules` table.

```
begin transaction
  delete from aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Places];

  declare @AutoID int;

  declare @NewId table (ID int, OldID int);

  -- In an insert statement you can't access the source table in the output clause unfortunately
  /*
  insert into aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Places] (ReferenceID, [Name], OtherKnownNames, [Description], Email)
      output Inserted.ID, P.ID into @NewId (ID, OldID)
      select ReferenceID, [Name], OtherKnownNames, [Description], Email
      from DB_A290D0_places.[dbo].[places] P
      where PublishingStatus = 0;
  */

  -- However in a merge statement you can access both the source and destination tables in the output clause.
  merge into aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Places] T
  using DB_A290D0_places.[dbo].[places] S on 1 = 0 -- always false
  when not matched by target and S.PublishingStatus = 0 then -- happens for every row, because 1 is never 0
    insert (ReferenceID, [Name], OtherKnownNames, [Description], Email)
      values (S.ReferenceID, S.[Name], S.OtherKnownNames, S.[Description], S.Email)
  output Inserted.ID, S.ID into into @NewId (ID, OldID);

  insert into aspnet_Website.[dbo].[Schedules] (Timing, [Type], PlaceID)
      select [Timing], [Type], P.ID
      from DB_A290D0_places.[dbo].[Schedules] S
      inner join @NewId P on P.OldId = S.PlaceId;
commit
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "P.ID" could not be bound, error in output line

Comment: with some modification it worked. I am not using OldID. thanx for your help.

Comment: I have corrected it - I don't see how your code can work given you are changing the parent ids.